# Heroku push master command giving error for node.js project

Tags: node.js, heroku

Kindly see the attached file to see the error I get when using the Heroku documentation to deploy a node.js project.
It gives me this error:
node version not specified.
Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Main",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
  "name": "Umeriftikhar",
  "email": ""
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "3.4.4",
 "jade": "*",
"stylus": "*",
"ejs" : "~0.8.5",               
"mongoose" : "~3.8.1",          
"passport" : "~0.1.17",         
"passport-local" : "~0.1.6",    
"passport-facebook" : "~1.0.2", 
"passport-twitter" : "~1.0.2",  
"passport-google-oauth" : "~0.1.5",
"connect-flash" : "~0.1.1",     
"bcrypt-nodejs" : "latest",

"morgan": "~1.0.0",
"body-parser": "~1.0.0",
"cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
"method-override": "~1.0.0",
"express-session": "~1.0.0" 
 },
 "engines": {
 "node": "4.2.1",
  "npm": "2.14.7"
 },
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/UmerIftikhar/Server.git"
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like a specific npm is failing during the install. Why don't you open a ssh shell and install individual npm to see which one errors

Comment: the same problem is discussed here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9766
But I cannot really understand the issue

Comment: did you specify nom version in your package.json?